# Can a 'save to pocket' be detected?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, pocket

I want to be able to track how many people save articles to Pocket from my page. I contacted Pocket support and they said that the Chrome extension doesn't emit an event when it's clicked. I was hoping to be able to drive a Google analytics goal when that happened.

I hacked the following together from the [MDN MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) docs, but it relies on Pocket not changing the classname of their UI. (And leaving it in the DOM, not as a separate overlay.)

```
var target = document.querySelector('body');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
    let a = document.getElementById('pkt_ext_master');
    if (a){
       console.log(a, "found a pocket save - firing a GA event!");
    }
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Pocket suggests that I look at their [Publisher stats](http://getpocket.com/publisher/), which is nice, but it's two sources of information. Does anyone have any inkling of how to do this more elegantly? Is it just up to Pocket to support it?